# Why is the horizontal stabilizer of the Lazair swept back?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, horizontal-stabilizer, lazair

Why is the horizontal stabilizer of the [Lazair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraflight_Lazair) swept back?

I understand the hinged elevators are perpendicular to the fuselage, but the horizontal stabilizer is actually swept back.